# Запуск и работа программ написанных для Prolog на php

Tags: prolog, php, linux

Допустим у меня есть программа написанная на Prolog, возможно ли её как-то запустить/выполнить используя php?

У меня сервер на линуксе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так (на примере swipl)

```
$prolog = "swipl -f example.pl -g goal,halt -t 'halt(1)'";
exec($prolog);
```

Comment: за SWI-Prolog спасибо. А синтаксис этой программы чем-то отличается от GNU Prolog ???

Answer (score 2):

Стандартные функции запуска внешних программ: 
[Управляющие функции: функции запуска программ](http://www.spravkaweb.ru/php/managfun/run/)